# Android native app: cannot scroll through the entire list which has around 200 elements (appium java client)

Tags: java, javascript, android, appium

I am working on Automating Android native app using java client.

The native app has a page with ListView which contains more 200 elements with textView objects arranged in alphabetical order and when I try scrolling with it scrolls until alphabet 'E' and then the app goes to the background and the @Test ends.

HashMap scrollObject = new HashMap();

```
RemoteWebElement element = (RemoteWebElement)driver.findElementById(fullListContainer);

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

String widId = ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId();

 //Text for search on the screen
scrollObject.put("text", tvProvidername);

scrollObject.put("element", widId);


js.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject);
```

Comment: "Automating Android native app" -- what do you mean? how do you automate the application?

Answer (score 0):

HI NRM below solution is For ANDROID NATIVE APP ONLY
What i am understanding is that , You want to scroll in the list form top (A) to bottom (Z) but when you start scrolling (if say Scroll from first element = A to Last element = Z )scrolling starts and scrolls to element = E and after that application under test goes to background and test stops if its correct then please try below code

For scrolling from A to bottom Z element

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).getChildByDescription(new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.TextView\").instance(0),\" YourLastElement (Z)\")");
```

YourLastElement (Z) = please put the description for last element here

Also if you want to Scroll from Top element to a desired element say M in the list simply change

YourLastElement (Z) = please put the description for M element here